# D3 Path: Transitioning only one end of a line

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, path

**Original code can be found at "[HERE](http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/d3ccbb29edf2c12de0b8)"**

I was able successfully draw linear lines using D3 Path generation.  I'd like to now take one of those lines and specifically transition **only** it's origin point by increasing the x value.

In the HTML view, the problem manifests itself in the HTML div titled: **"Transition the Origin End (or Top) of Path in an HTML Div"**, where a green line/path is rendered.

The original data used to render the line is:

```
  var lineSet1 = [
    { "x": 0,   "y": 0},
    { "x": 50,  "y": 50}];
```

The function I'm using to draw and transition the path is:

```
  // This function is meant to transition only the origin point of a line.
  function drawTransitioningOriginPath( dataSet, selectString, color, fill, strokeWidth, svgWidth, svgHeight, interpolationType ) {

    //This is the accessor function we talked about above
    var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
        .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
        .interpolate(interpolationType);

    //The SVG Container
    var svgContainer = d3.select(selectString).append("svg")
        .attr("width", svgWidth)
        .attr("height", svgHeight);

    //The line Path we draw
    var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
        .attr("d", lineFunction(dataSet))
        .attr("stroke", color)
        .attr("stroke-width", strokeWidth*2)
        .attr("fill", fill);

     lineGraph.select("path").transition() //<=== TRYING TO TRANSITION THE ORIGIN HERE
         .duration(500)
         .ease("linear")
         .attr("d", lineFunction(function(d, i){
           if(i == 0){
             newX = d.x + 1;
             return d.x = d.newX;
           }
         }));

   }
```

In the example, I'm trying to swing the origin point, which is the top of the line, from left to right, one increment (i.e. "+1") at a time.

My logic is that as I try to invoke the transition, I should first isolate the data set where the index "i" is equal to 0, so I can isolate the end of the path that represents the origin and then increment the "x" coordinate by 1, in order to start transitioning it.  The reason I'd like to increment by one (1) is so that (later) I'll be able to reverse the increment as x becomes equal to the width of the SVG canvas, like a car's wiper blade, going back and forth.

When I execute the code, I get the following error in the browser: **TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'd.x')**

Comment: You would need to pass only a subset of the bound data to `lineFunction` in each iteration. That is, you'd do something line `.attr("d", function(d) { return lineFunction(d.slice(start)); })` where `start` is 0 at the beginning and `d.length` at the end. I would use a custom attribute tween to compute the correct length for each time step, using an interpolator between 0 and `d.length`.

Comment: Sorry Lars.  I appreciate the help but I'm not advanced enough in my knowledge of D3 to understand what you're suggesting.  I've been trying to dissect what you suggested (with tests) but I'm not making any progress with it.

Comment: So just to clarify, what you're looking for is a "reverse" drawing of the path where it starts out as the full path and then the starting point moves towards the end until the line vanishes, right?

Comment: No.  I want to move the starting point to the right, where only "x" in the coordinate increments.  This would cause the top of the line to move to the right while the bottom of the line stays constant (like the wiper blade of a car).  Thanks.

Comment: Ah ok. For this you can just use different data http://jsfiddle.net/nq2kL34d/

Comment: Thanks.  This works for a single transition (from left to right).  You created a default second data and bound it for the transition, using .datum().  I tried to enhance this a little by creating a function that attempts to toggle "x" (in a copied array) so that the line will transition back and forth, continuously.  I still can't get it transition when I try to use a function to bind data.  I noticed that if I use .datum(getNewData) it doesn't call the "getNewData" function but if I use .data(getNewData) it calls the function but doesn't transition.  I put the updated code into the gist. Thx

Comment: Well you do have to actually call the function -- `getNewData()`.

Comment: Corrected the calling of the function using ".datum("d", getNewData())" and, while the getNewData function gets called and I can step through it with the debugger, doing so doesn't execute the transition.  Thx.

Comment: Could you narrow it down to a minimal example please?

Comment: I'm going to close this post as successful, as you were right about how to get the original transition to work.  The constant transitioning warrants a new question.  Thanks for your help!